# Electric shock: positive vs negative voltage

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, charge, voltage

A high voltage wire can either have an large excess of electrons (net negative charge density), or a large defect of electrons (net positive charge density).

The voltage difference between the wire and the human can be positive or negative.

Are both cases equally dangerous? Is there a difference between electric shock from a positive wire and from a negative wire?

(In one case electrons will rush into my body, in the other electrons will rush out of my body)

Answer (score 1):

Electric shock potential is based on the available voltage and current. It is the current, not the voltage, which causes electric shock. The  thresholds for these parameters for various physiological effects on the on body the in the literature make no mention of polarity that I can find. *See IEC 60479-1: Effects of current on human beings and livestock Part 1.*

Thus it would appear that the polarity of the voltage and direction of the current are irrelevant.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The electrons rush *through* your body. The direction is rather irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

> A high voltage wire can either have an large excess of electrons (net negative charge density), or a large defect of electrons (net positive charge density).

The excess or deficit of electrons is very slight: it doesn't take much to make a large potential difference. The capability of the source that sets up the potential difference to drive a current matters a great deal, though.

> (In one case electrons will rush into my body, in the other electrons will rush out of my body)

It's current *through* your body that matters. Current through living tissue isn't electrons at all: it's ions. Electrochemical reactions at your skin convert the metallic electron current to the aqueous ion current.

The polarity doesn't matter because as much current flows out as flows in.